# Downthemall missing window elements

Tags: firefox-extensions

I have noticed that [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) is having some sort of problem.  It's missing the usual window bar at the top with the window controls and, in my case, blue bar.  See pic below.  I can right click on the left side and get window controls, as well as drag it around, so I'm not sure if this is a bug or feature.

I tried tracking down the forums for this extension, but it appears that the domain expired a few days ago.

I've tried resetting the extension to defaults, and no change.  There aren't any options related to this as far as I can tell anyways.  I will try restarting Firefox and rebooting next.  I'm in the middle of something else I'd have done it already.

Is this a bug or a feature?  How do I get the top bar back?

Downthemall 3.0.8, Firefox 55.03, Windows 7 Ultimate N 64 bit

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this appears to be a bug with current versions of DownThemAll and Firefox 55+. The only way I have found to solve this is to downgrade back to Firefox 54.0.1 or earlier.

Note that [due to changes in Firefox 57 regarding the adoption of WebExtensions](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/02/16/the-road-to-firefox-57-compatibility-milestones/) (with FF57 likely being mainstream released around October 2017), DTA will likely need significant rewriting to continue working in the future and it's not clear yet whether or not those updates will occur.

So for now, if DTA is important to you, you may need to keep two copies of Firefox (pre and post FF55) to continue using it for a while.

---

*Update: [DownThemAll has been rewritten](https://www.downthemall.net/) for current versions of Firefox and is [available via the Mozilla Addons webstore](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/).*

---

Comment: I think the webextension thing is going to cause a fork, or people to stay on the old one, until new extensions replace older workhorses.

Answer (score 3):

The problem I suspect brings many here is not simply that *DownThemAll*'s Title Bar is missing, but that as a consequence it is impossible to reposition its window.

When I read [in Dan Whaley's question](https://superuser.com/q/1246513/460302),

> I can right click on the left side and get window controls, as well as drag it around

I began to experiment, and discovered that, in my case at least (Windows 7 Pro, FireFox 55.0.3 (32-bit), DownThemAll 3.0.8), **there is a portion of *DownThemAll*'s window that can be used in lieu of the Title Bar for repositioning** (see my illustration).  Note that you can also right-click in this region and select Minimize.

[image: Where to left-click and drag]

Comment: Yep, that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

[Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) (currently 52.3.0) still has appropriate support for older extensions, also those using XULRunner. Needless to say, [DTA](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) demonstrates glitchless work with FF ESR. Note that newer FF version shares profile folder with the ESR one, but I haven't encountered any issues so far using them both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS in a [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) style to get the titlebar and min/max/close buttons back:

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

#DownThemAll #titlebar {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-titlebar-maximized;
  -moz-window-dragging: drag;
}
#DownThemAll #titlebar-min {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-minimize;
}
#DownThemAll #titlebar-max {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-maximize;
}
#DownThemAll #titlebar-close {
  -moz-appearance: -moz-window-button-close;
}
```

Edit:
This brings the 'Online/Offline' button back:

```
#DownThemAll statusbarpanel#netstatus {
  list-style-image: url("chrome://dta/skin/win/netstatus-aero.png");
  -moz-image-region: rect(0, 16px, 16px, 0);
}
#DownThemAll statusbarpanel#netstatus[offline] {
  -moz-image-region: rect(0, 32px, 16px, 16px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I tried to create a new style, but still have negative result. Can you share a step-by-step instruction on how to do this with Stylish please?

Comment: [1] Install Stylish, and add the button to the Firefox toolbar.
[2] Select 'blank style' from the Stylish toolbar button.
[3] Copy and paste the CSS code above into the new blank style, and click on the 'save' button.
[4] It should end up looking similar to this.

[1]: https://userstyles.org/help/stylish_firefox
[2]: https://i.imgur.com/zPk4eEx.png
[3]: https://i.imgur.com/tFLacKz.png
[4]: https://i.imgur.com/aDAWm9e.png

Comment: Done --- thank you. What about menu bar? How can I try to restore it?

Comment: Not sure which menu bar you're referring to. Got a screenshot?

Comment: Please see the following screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVSEL.png

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing a menu bar in the DTA Manager. Can't see one using Google Images either: https://www.google.com/search?q=downthemall&tbm=isch --- Funnily enough, I found the Github issue for the OP question too: https://github.com/downthemall/downthemall/issues/246

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by building DTA yourself.

1. checkout DTA with tag:3.0.8

https://github.com/downthemall/downthemall-legacy/

2. cherry-pick this commit

https://github.com/downthemall/downthemall-legacy/commit/a39d3987f55b987087eb63bd4d31cdfb81f1d0d3#diff-864ea9bc478318c39c4589422d097255

3. build it with make.py. you will need python 2.x.

   python.exe make.py dta-3.0.8-fix.xpi --release

also note this is not a perfect solution; manager window still appears slightly different from older FF.